# How to plot a series using different colors depending on the y-value

Tags: plotting, color

I have a sequence of numbers ${x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n}$.

I would like to plot the sequence using ListLinePlot but use a different color depending on if the values $x_i$ are within $a_i<x_i<b_i$.

For example, if $x_1$ is between $[0,1)$, blue, if it is between $[1,2)$, red, and [1,3), green, etc.

Answer (score 11):

Taking Rahul's extension of Michael's answer a step further, using `MeshShading` instead of `ColorFunction`:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 3}, 100];
ListLinePlot[data, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{1, 2}},
 MeshShading -> {Blue, Red, Green}, MeshStyle -> None]
```

[image]

**Update:** Although my preferred method is using `MeshShading`, you can also get a similar result using a combination of `Interpolation`, `Plot` and a piecewise `ColorFunction` as follows:

```
ClearAll[pwColorF];
pwColorF[thresholds : {___}, colors : {___} : ColorData[1, "ColorList"]][a_] := 
 Module[{tc = Transpose[{colors[[;; Length@thresholds]],
                         Function[{x, y}, x < a <= y] @@@
                         Partition[Join @@ {{-Infinity}, Most@thresholds, {Infinity}}, 2, 1]}]},
        Piecewise[tc]]

intF = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

Plot[Quiet@intF[x], {x, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 ColorFunction -> (pwColorF[{1, 2, 3}, {Blue, Red, Green}][#2] &),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's the actual right way to do this. I keep forgetting: `ColorFunction` is for smooth colours, `MeshShading` is for flat colours. Right?

Comment: @Rahul, i think you are right. `ColorFunction` assigns the colors to vertices of a single line with many vertices (i.e., it determines `VertexColors`) with blending when the two vertices of a line segment have different colors, while with `MeshShading`  each line segment gets its own color. without any blending

Answer (score 10):

A small extension of Michael E2's answer to better match how I understand the question:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 3}, 100];
ListLinePlot[data, 
 ColorFunction -> (Switch[#2, y_ /; y < 1, Blue, y_ /; y < 2, Red, y_ /; y < 3, Green] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{0.9, 1.1, 1.9, 2.1}}, MeshStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 3}, 100];

ListLinePlot[data, 
 ColorFunction -> (Switch[#2, y_ /; y < 1/3, Blue, y_ /; y < 2/3, Red, y_ /; y < 3/3, Green] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here's a variation:

```
ListLinePlot[data, 
 ColorFunction -> (Switch[#2, y_ /; y < 1, Blue, y_ /; y < 2, Red, y_ /; y < 3, Green] &),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```