# Plot that draws a dashed/solid curve depending on the y-value of the curve

Tags: plotting

Kind of as an extension of this question: [How to plot a series using different colors depending on the y-value](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59951/how-to-plot-a-series-using-different-colors-depending-on-the-y-value)

Is there something similar to `MeshFunction` or `ColorFunction` that can control whether a curve being plotted is dashed vs solid depending on the y-value?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A simple modification of the answer in the linked Q/A:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 3}, 100];
ListLinePlot[data, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{1, 2}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Blue, Directive[Red, Dashed], Green}, MeshStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Use `MeshShading -> {Dashing[.02], Dashing[None], Dotted}` to get

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast answer! Just a quick question about how to apply it. If I want to dash when the absolute value is greater than 1, this code produces weird results. Any idea?

`data = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, 100];
ListLinePlot[data, MeshFunctions -> {Abs[#2] &}, Mesh -> {{1}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Blue, Directive[Red, Dashed]}, 
 MeshStyle -> None]`

Comment: @Hanmyo, i am getting the same "weird results"  with `Abs[#2]&`. I don't know why; maybe a bug? Meanwhile, a work-around is to use `ListLinePlot[data, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{-1, 1}}, MeshShading -> {Blue, Directive[Red, Dashed]}, MeshStyle -> None]`. Btw, thank you for the accept.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I'll post it as a separate question, as I'm looking to do something more complicated involving `Abs`.