# How to prevent ColorFunction from blending colors between points on a ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, color

I am trying to style the line differently above a value, in this case 100, but when I use ColorFunction the line is blurred, showing a purple color near the 100 line. Ideally, it would switch from blue to red without any blur between.

```
data = {13.4, 16, 18.6, 23.2, 15.4, 19.2, 14.4, 17.2, 15.4, 19.6, 15, 20.8, 
250, 320, 630, 459.9, 655.2, 693, 567, 310, 300, 196, 24.4, 23.8, 17.2, 22, 12.6, 
15, 24.2, 13.6, 25.6, 16.2, 15.4, 23.2, 24.2, 18.2, 18, 23.4, 19.2, 13.2, 19, 
24.6, 20, 18.4, 21, 186, 485, 579.6, 422.1, 485.1, 598.5, 472.5, 480, 276, 192, 
12.8, 12.6, 19.4, 12.8, 23.4, 19.6, 15.8, 18, 18.8, 25.6, 152, 420, 541.8, 793.8, 
434.7, 441, 642.6, 355, 252, 210, 19, 24.8, 19.8, 16.4, 24.6, 16.4, 16.6, 15, 
20.6, 25.4, 20.8, 15, 15.8};

ListLinePlot[
    data, 
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[y > 100, Red, Blue]],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False
]
```

[image: Resultant Graph]

I believe the reason for the blur is that no points lie very close the line, so the color function blurs the area between these points. If I add points to the data like `99, 101` the color change will be abrupt but it obviously changes the data as seen below in the first spike.[image: Resultant Graph 2]

Is there a way to add an abrupt color change without changing the data?

Comment: Replace `ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[y > 100, Red, Blue]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False` with `MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{100}}, MeshShading -> {Red, Blue}, MeshStyle -> None`. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59951/484

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few hacks that achieve your result. This will at least let you do what you're going to do, but there may be more direct methods. You can plot the data twice with `PlotRangeClipping->True` over two different ranges and combine the two plots:

```
Show[
 ListLinePlot[
  data, PlotRangeClipping -> True
  , PlotRange -> {All, {0, 100}}
  , PlotStyle -> Blue
  ],
 ListLinePlot[
  data, PlotRangeClipping -> True
  , PlotRange -> {All, {100, Max@data}}
  , PlotStyle -> Red
  ]
 , PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

Which gives:

[image]

Or you can plot an interpolated list to fill in the gaps:

```
int = Table[
   {i, Interpolation[MapIndexed[{First@#2, #1} &, data], 
      InterpolationOrder -> 1][i]}
   , {i, 1, Length@data, 0.01}
   ];

ListLinePlot[
 int,
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[y > 100, Red, Blue]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False
 ]
```

Which gives:

[image]